# How to make Filemaker textbox resizable according to content

Tags: textbox, filemaker, autoresize

I'd like to create a layout to show this table in list view, the point is to make the text field resizable according to content. I have try several method, but all fails. I am using FileMaker 12.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In Browse and Find modes, if a field isn't set to have a scroll bar, the field will expand while the user is entering data, but only then. It will return to the default size when the user navigates to another field or another record.
- In Preview mode, you can make the field larger than it could possibly need and set it to slide up and also reduce the size of the enclosing part. But the user won't be able to interact with the interface of the layout (can't click buttons, change data, etc.).
- A workaround might be to use a tooltip. If you set the tooltip to the contents of the field itself, then the user can hover over the field to see any expanded contents.
- If you *really* need exactly the functionality that you mention (which I would define as having field height and enclosing body part expand in list view based on the field's content length while in FileMaker), the only way I could see doing it would be to use custom web publishing to create a web page and use FileMaker's web viewer to show that web page. [F 'n' web](http://blog.jsfmp.com/post/88307579211/responsive-web-viewer-layouts-fmp-url-javascript-demo) has an article that might be of some assistance if you go this route.

Answer (score 1):

For Browse mode you can set layout objects to dynamically resize  based on the layout size, but not on the object contents. If you need this functionality in Browse mode you will probably need to use a web-viewer.

In Preview mode you can use sliding left and sliding up for reduction of the size of the layout objects, but there is no option to expand.

Comment: Thank you @nicolai.kant, your answer is also correct, it is almost impossible to auto readjust height with the content of textbox.  But there is only one I can mark as "answer".